# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'

Tags: python, sql, json, python-3.x, postgresql

I have **sql** class in **python** which inserts data to my PostgreSQL DB . In my table, one column is **jsonfield** and when I insert data to that table , i get error **(psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict') .**

I have used **json.load , json.loads , json.dump , json.dumps**. None of them worked. Even I tried string formatting. It did not work, either.

Any idea how to do?

my  code is as following

```
json_data = {
 "key": "value"
 }
query = """INSERT INTO  table(json_field) VALUES(%s)"""
self.cursor.execute(query, ([json_data,]))
self.connection.commit()
```

Comment: can you be more specific about what didn't work when using `json.dumps()` to create a JSON string?

Comment: Reading the docs [JSON adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#adapt-json) would be a good start.

Comment: There are seven answers in the linked duplicate. If _none_ of them work for you, please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] .

Comment: While I wouldn't use the solution in the accepted answer personally (using adaption is more convenient), [it seems to work just fine for your example](https://pastebin.com/EagCiBnQ).

Comment: @ElvinJafarov, what's "unfair" about it? A dupe's a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

Below block of code worked for me

```py
import psycopg2
import json

json_data = {
 "key": "value"
 }

json_object = json.dumps(json_data, indent = 4)  

query = """INSERT INTO  json_t(field) VALUES(%s)"""

dbConn = psycopg2.connect(database='test', port=5432, user='username')
cursor=dbConn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query, ([json_object,]))
dbConn.commit()
```

Comment: This can be simplified by using the built in [JSON adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#adapt-json)